# Ajax call not work with IE and CHROME

Tags: javascript

I trie to get JSON Data from my beispielDaten.json file.
In Firefox the Site, which i build dynamic with the JSON Data works fine. But in IE and Chrome i got the error: Access denied.
So what i've done wrong ?
Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "js/beispielDaten.json",
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function(daten) {

    var className = '';
    var orange = "orange";
    $.each(daten, function (key, val) {
    className = "range" + key;
    }

    $('.container').html(html);
 },error: function (request, status, error) { alert(status + ", " + error); }
  });
 $.getScript("js/inputRange.js");
 });
```

And here is my json file:

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "title":"Auftreten und Ausstrahlung",
      "description":"Wirkung, Haltung, Körpersprache, Selbstsicherheit, Temperament"
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "title":"Fachliche Kompetenz",
      "description":"Bringt erforderliches Knowhow mit?"
   },
   {
      "id":"3",
      "title":"Sozialkompetenz",
      "description":"Teamfähig? Rolle in Gruppen? Hilfsbereitschaft? Reaktion in Engpasssituationen?"
   },
   {
      "id":"4",
      "title":"Zielorientierung & Leistungsbereitschaft",
      "description":"Erreicht gesteckte Ziele? Ehrgeiz? Motivation?"
   },
   {
      "id":"5",
      "title":"Kommentar"
   }
]
```

The only thing i got in Firefox debugger is **XML-Verarbeitungsfehler: Syntax-Fehler**

Many thx

Comment: First of all ... are you properly testing this via HTTP(S), or are you messing around with `file://` in the browser ...? In case it is the latter, the answer to your problem is the former: Go set up a proper local test environment, including a web server, first.

Comment: "But in IE and Chrome i got the error: Access denied" — What is the exact error message? Where is it being displayed?

Comment: You are making a POST request and claiming that you are POSTing JSON, but there is no `data`, so you aren't POSTing anything.